# Opening Google Maps Map on button click, phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, google-maps, phonegap-build

My HTML (I am trying to insert a map into the `div` after the button is clicked):

```
...

<div id="map"></div>

...

<button id="location">log your location</button>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxmyapikeyxxx&callback=">
</script>

...
```

My javascript code (I am trying to adhere to the rules of phonegap, by adding an `addEventListener` to the `click` and creating a map when the button is clicked:

```
...

onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    document.getElementById("camera").addEventListener("click", function() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imagePath){
            document.getElementById("photoImg").setAttribute("src", imagePath);
        }, function(){
            alert("Photo cancelled");
        }, {
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
        });
    }, false);

    document.getElementById("location").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var map;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 8
        });
    });
},

...
```

I am trying to populate the `div` with id `map` with a map when the button with id `location` is clicked.

Comment: @dwij here is the question

Answer (score 0):

Used this for the call to the google maps api:

`<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAffJ2OZVv3lSo-tWqZ-MpVDLoMSLzYLiM&callback=">
</script>`

I placed the above code directly below the button.

No changes made to index.js.

I think maybe the reason it works is because I added this CSS to the index.css file for the div with id `map`:

`#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    position: absolute;
}`